# why the blackslash is not url encoded in this shell script?

Tags: shell, awk, urlencode

I am trying to the url encode a string based on shell scripting. 
I have downloaded a script from internet.
it is:

```
#!/bin/sh
url_encoder() 
{                                                                                                                                                                                                              

echo -n "$1" | awk -v ORS="" '{ gsub(/./,"&\n") ; print }' | while read l;
do                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

case "$l" in                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  [-_.~/a-zA-Z0-9] ) echo -n ${l} ;;                                                                                                                                                                                      
      "" ) echo -n %20 ;;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
       * ) printf '%%%02X' "'$l"                                                                                                                                                                                          
esac                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

done              
}

echo ""

}
```

The basic idea of the above codes is to
(1) convert a input string into the rows, each row has one character
(2) for each row, url encode the character

So If I run

```
$url_encoder "abc:"
```

the output would be "abc%3A", which is correct

But if I run

```
$url_encoder "\\"      # I want to encode the backslash, so I use 2 "\" here
```

there is no output at all.

Do you know the reason why?

Comment: Who is using the output of `url_encoder`? Something like `curl` or `wget` should have a way of encoding its inputs as necessary.

Comment: the output of url_encoder should be hashed firstly according to the requirement.

Answer (score 4):

no need to use read which is slow, variable expansion can do a substring, no need to handle the space character specially, it can be handled as the default

```
url_encoder() {
    local i str=$1 c
    for ((i=0;i<${#str};i+=1)); do
        c=${str:i:1}
        case "$c" in
            [-_.~/a-zA-Z0-9] ) echo -n "${c}" ;;
            * ) printf '%%%02X' "'$c" ;;
        esac
    done
}
 l='\'
 printf '%%%02X' "'$l"
```

The reason why the backslash disapears is because it has a special meaning for `read`, `-r` option should be used to avoid.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read

Note `~` should also be encoded http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

printf argument starting with a quote (single or double), handles only ascii character "'$c" (<128).

```
url_encoder() { (
    LC_ALL=C
    str=$1
    for ((i=0;i<${#str};i+=1)); do
        c=${str:i:1}
        if [[ $c = [-_./a-zA-Z0-9] ]]; then
            echo -n "${c}"
        elif [[ $c = [$'\1'-$'\x7f'] ]]; then
            printf '%%%02X' "'$c"
        else
            printf '%%%s' $(echo -n "$c" | od  -An -tx1)
        fi
    done
)}
```

Comment: yes, "read -r" works. thanks for the other two versions of url encoder. But it is not the bash script, it is "#!/bin/sh", so some syntax (such as for ((i=0;i<${#str};i+=1));) might not be supported.

Comment: using `read` will lead to other problems IFS must be unset to distinguish between spaces, tabs and newlines for example `IFS= read -r`; however it will be very slow `sh` is clearly not the good tool

Comment: if `bash` specific can't be used the question should not be tagged `bash`

Comment: this shell script is actually running in the embeded system environment. Bash is not available in the environment, only sh is available.

Answer (score 1):

[Nahuel Fouilleul's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44517651/45375) explains the problem with your approach (`-r` is missing from your `read` command, resulting in unwanted interpretation of `\` chars.) and offers a more efficient `bash` solution.

Here's a more efficient, POSIX-compliant solution (`sh`-compatible) that performs the encoding with a single `awk` command, assuming that the input string is composed only of characters in the ASCII/Unicode code-point range between 32 and 127, inclusively:

```
#!/bin/sh

url_encoder()
{                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  awk -v url="$1" -v ORS= 'BEGIN {
     # Create lookup table that maps characters to their code points.
    for(n=32;n<=127;n++) ord[sprintf("%c",n)]=n
     # Process characters one by one, either passing them through, if they
     # need no encoding, or converting them to their %-prefixed hex equivalent.
    for(i=1;i<=length(url);++i) {
      char = substr(url, i, 1) 
      if (char !~ "[-_.~/a-zA-Z0-9]") char = sprintf("%%%x", ord[char])
      print char
    }
    printf "\n"
  }'
}
```